# efficient way to get the adjacency list of a network?

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

Consider this simple example

```
pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,1,2,3,4],
              'place' : ['bar','pool','bar','kitchen','bar']})

Out[4]: 
   id    place
0   1      bar
1   1     pool
2   2      bar
3   3  kitchen
4   4      bar
```

Here the network structure is such that a given `id` is connected to another `id` if they went to the same place.

For instance, here  `1` is connected to `2` and `4` because they are at the `bar`.

`1` and `3` are NOT connected because `1` went to `bar` and `pool` which does not include `kitchen` (the only place `3` went to)

My real data is huge, about 500k. What is the most efficient way to proceed to get the `adjacency list`? Here this is just a string with the format `source target target` like in https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/readwrite.adjlist.html

```
adjacency_list
1 2 4
2 1 4
4 1 2
```

Can we avoid loops and use Pandas tricks?

Thanks!

Comment: so if more than 2 id went to the same place, do we place them under the same edge_df row?

Comment: thanks for the comment. I meant the `adjacency list` indeed. let me edit the question

Comment: for example , 1 --b 1--c 2--d 3--c 3--d will 1 and 2 connected ?

Comment: @W-B I dont think so. 1 only went to be and c while 2 went to d

Comment: df.groupby('place').id.unique()?

Comment: @W-B, that would be ideal but the desired outcome he wants is different :)

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but are you trying to find the shortest path between two points?  If so, you want to use a shortest path algorithm.  Perhaps Dijkstra's Algorithm.

Or, I just have no idea what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `unique` then switch the column 0 to 1 and column 1 to 0 `concat` the both df together

```
adj=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('place').id.unique().loc[lambda x : x.str.len()>1].tolist())
pd.concat([adj,adj.rename(columns={0:1,1:0})])
Out[810]: 
   0  1
0  1  2
0  2  1
```

Update :

```
newdf=df.merge(df,on='place')
x=nx.from_pandas_dataframe(newdf,'id_x','id_y') # using merge to get the connect for all id by link columns place. 
[list(itertools.permutations(x, len(x)) for x in list(nx.connected_components(x))] # using permutations get the all combination for each  connected_components in networkx 
Out[821]: [[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]]
```

Data input

```
df
Out[822]: 
   id place
0   1   bar
1   1  pool
2   2   bar
3   3   bar
```

Comment: nice but would that work with multiple targets for the same source?

Comment: sounds promising. do you mind explaining a bit whats going on with the update? thanks!

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ added , since if we need to create the network we need two column , you only have one column id and another is the link place ,we using the link to create another missing column , then we can using networkx

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
>>> df
   id    place
0   1      bar
1   1     pool
2   2      bar
3   3  kitchen
>>> df.groupby('place').id.nunique().value_counts()
1    2
2    1
Name: id, dtype: int64
```